# Finalizer with CodeDom?

Tags: c#, .net, codedom, finalizer

Is it possible to add a Finalizer to a CodeDom generated class (other than using CodeSnippetTypeMember)?

I couldn't find any information about it on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known bug in .NET Framework and was reported some time back at
http://lab.msdn.microsoft.com/ProductFeedback/viewFeedback.aspx?feedbackId=FDBK48431

But the link above is currently not working. You can view it using internet archive on the following link
http://web.archive.org/web/20080224200911rn_2/connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=97599

I am not sure whether it was fixed or not.